# How can the ConstantLine LineWidth property default be set?

Tags: matlab

With MATLAB R2018b, using `set(groot,'defaultConstantLineLineWidth',2)` should set the `ConstantLine`'s `LineWidth` default property to `2`, but it gives the following error:

```
Error using matlab.ui.Root/set
constantlinelinewidth is an invalid class name
```

How can this default property be set?

This property would affect the vertical line drawn by `xline()`, for example:

```
x=[1:10];
y=x.^2;
plot(x,y);
xline(4);
```

I am following [this resource](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html)

Comment: Which MATLAB version/release are you using?

Comment: When I follow the link, it explains `defaultLineLineWidth`, not `defaultConstantLineLineWidth`

Comment: Yes @Daniel, but setting `defaultLineLineWidth` does not affect the line drawn by `xline()`. Further investigation (using `get()` on the axes handle) showed that the line drawn by `xline()` is actually under a different type called `ConstantLine` with the associated property `LineWidth`. Following the format described in the link suggests I can set the default with `set(groot,'defaultConstantLineLineWidth',2)`. However this gives the error described in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

`ConstantLine`'s `LineWidth` default property cannot be set in MATLAB R2018b using `set(groot,'defaultConstantLineLineWidth',2)` due to a known inconsistency in this release of MATLAB. See [discussion](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/500128-how-can-the-constantline-linewidth-property-default-be-set#comment_785795).

Answer (score 0):

As a kludge, you could do something like:

```
x=[1:10];
y=x.^2;
plot(x,y);
hold on
plot(4*[1,1], [min(y), max(y)], 'LineWidth', 3)
```